# How to retrieve the path to a client machine Special Folders running RemoteApp as a filepath string?

Tags: c#, remote-access, terminal-services

```
// Set default workspace directory
string initialDirectoryString = @"C:\work\";
// Check if remote session, and get the local drive location
if(System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation.TerminalServerSession) {
    initialDirectoryString = @"\\tsclient\C\work\";
}
```

Originally when I wrote the above code, I was under the impression that we could create a directory in `C:\` to write to, but from what I've been told, the only location they have acces to is the `My Documents` directory.

So, I know I can retrieve the local `Environment.SpecialFolder` with:

```
string path = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
```

The problem is how to retrieve from the client machine. I thought about retrieving the path from the server and prepending `\\tsclient\` (and removing the `:` from `C:` etc.), but then if the `My Documents` directory isn't the same on the client as (`V:` instead of `D:`, for example), then I would get an `Access Denied` when I try to write to the location.

Is there a way to that I can specify a string similar to CMD where you can use `%USERPROFILE%/My Documents`, but with `tsclient`?

Edit: I found that I can use `Environment.ExpandEnvironmentalVariables()` to change the `%USERPROFILE%\My Documents` to an absolute path.

```
string MyDocumentsLocation = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(@"%USERPROFILE%\My Documents");
```

Comment: Hi, I am on the same road. Have you solved your problem somehow?